Shopify theme editor removes event listener's in section update
I created a simple custom section with one button, and one schema setting (a checkbox). I also created a script where I added an event listener to the button. The problem is that the first time the custom section is loaded the button listener works properly, but once I change any settings of the section, in this case, the checkbox, the button event listener stops working and the event doesn't fire anymore.
In the docs I found that with every change in the section setting the HTML will be re-rendered, added, or removed, that means that every time the section is updated I have to add all the event listeners again, and 'restart' all the DOOM related logic that I had done in javascript?
Thanks a lot, here is the code in case it helps
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <button id="button1" type="button">
    Click me
  </button>
</div>

<script>
  const button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");
  button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Hello world');
  });
</script>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Custom Section",
    "tag": "section",
    "limit": 1,
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "checkbox",
        "label": "Checkbox",
      }
    ],
    "blocks": [],
    "presets": [
      {
        "name": "Custom Section",
        "blocks": []
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}


The problem could be resolved by ensuring that the necessary JavaScript is re-executed when a specific section of the page is reloaded.
document.addEventListener('shopify:section:load', function () {
    handleButtonClick("===>> Hello world reloaded!!! <<=== ");
});

Complete Code Snippet:
<div class="section-wrapper">
    <button id="button1" type="button">
        Click me
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    function handleButtonClick(optionalValue = '') {
        const button1 = document.querySelector("#button1");

        button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(`${optionalValue ? optionalValue : ' ===> Hello world! <=== '}`);
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        handleButtonClick();
    });

    /* 
        Re-execute any JavaScript needed for the section to work and display properly, 
        as if the page had just been loaded. 
    */
    document.addEventListener('shopify:section:load', function () {
        handleButtonClick("===>> Hello world reloaded!!! <<=== ");
    });
</script>

{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "Test Section",
        "tag": "section",
        "limit": 1,
        "settings": [
            {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "id": "checkbox",
                "label": "Checkbox"
            }
        ],
        "blocks": [],
        "presets": [
            {
                "name": "Test Section",
                "blocks": []
            }
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}

